# Register class as PDO driver

Tags: php, pdo

Can I somehow register php class as PDO driver?

To clarify my question. PDO driver works with dsn (for example `mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test`) where first part is which driver to use. In this example it is mysql and therefore it uses php extension pdo_mysql. Can I register new driver from php pointing on class?

Something like this:

```php
PDO::registerDriver('foo', \Foo::class); // I know this does not exists and I'm asking if there is some way to do this
print_r(PDO::getAvailableDrivers());

// outputs: Array( [0] => mysql, [1] => foo )
```

*I know I can extend and override php PDO and PDOStatement classes, but that is not what I'm asking.*

I was looking into php source code but I'm not familiar with C/C++. Here is a [link](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/pdo/pdo_dbh.c#L1189) for function PDO::getAvailableDrivers if somebody is interested.

Comment: Are you trying to achieve multi database connection or something like this ?

Comment: @AtikHashmee I'm trying to connect to type of database which doesn't have pdo driver. I want to create own but make it compatible.

Comment: Understood. I don't think, the way you are looking with PHP built-in function. don't think won't be possible. you have to make your own registerDriver function and then put your custom driver and built-in driver. that's how you can achieve what you want